# How to solve this linear set of equations using W|A?

Tags: linear-algebra, wolfram-alpha

I try to solve a simple system of four linear equations in the variables `ch1, ch2, co1 and co2:`

`Solve[{ch2 - ch1 == dch , co2 - co1 == dco , ch1*t1 + co1*t1 - co1 == 0, ch2*t2 + co2*t2 - co2 == 0}, {ch1, ch2, co1, co2}]`

where: `t1, t2, dch and dco` are constants.

I cannot figure out what is going wrong. W|A relpies "Wolfram|Alpha doesn't understand your query".

I think the above is very similar to

```
Solve[{2 x - y == 0, -x + 2 y - z == -1, -3 y + 4 z == 4 a}, {x, y, z}]
```

which works well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is ch1 etc a single variable? If so, replace it with a single letter

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha doesn't like variables with more than one character and doesn't like the asterisk symbol * as multiplication. It's a bit dumb like that. If you replace the multi-character variables with single letters, and replace strings such as 'x*y' with 'x(y)' then everything should work fine [like so](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7By-x==a,%20w-z==b,%20x%28t%29%2bz%28t%29-z==0,%20y%28s%29%2bw%28s%29-w==0%7D,%20%7Bx,%20y,%20z,%20w%7D%5D).